What causes the Garbage Collector to spike and drop the framerate here?
I'm trying to optimize my first game project. It reaches between 55-60 FPS while playing, but there is a problem. As in the screenshot, the Garbage Collector section sometimes causes increases. This sometimes causes unstable FPS while playing the game. How exactly can I solve this?


Without seeing your code, all we can say is "you're allocating garbage somewhere. When enough garbage piles up, the garbage collector runs and reduces performance". We can see you're allocating 56.3 kB of memory, 42.6 kB in coroutines, but you've cut off any deeper information in this screenshot. Try enabling Deep Profile mode and look carefully at the GC Alloc column: what parts of your project are allocating memory? Once you identify those worst offenders, share the relevant code or instructions for how to reproduce the problem. Then we can help you find less garbage-intensive alternatives.

Also, when profiling in Editor, check whetehr the spikes come from the Editor itself.

I will write after doing what you said.

are you assigning strings anywhere?
